# I wrongly flagged a question. What to do?

Tags: discussion, flagging, exact-duplicates

I just wrongly flagged the question [Is this correct? $rH=Hr^{-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330366) as a duplicate of the question [Show that the set $\{r^{-1} : r\in R \}$ contains exactly one element out of each right coset of $H$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330236). While the questions are related, they are not the same. Unfortunately, I only realized that when the first answers showed up.

It seems that there is no way for me to revoke the flag. I've tried to raise a second flag explaining my error, but it turned out that more than one flag on the same question is not allowed. Is there any way to tell the moderators they should ignore that flag (and thus saving them time)? What is the correct behavior in this situation?

Comment: Related feature-request: [Cancel misclicked flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87500/146482)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hum, difficult to answer here. I guess one option is to pop into chat and see if any of us is there. Or see if you can get someone else (preferably 10K) to dispute your flag; quite a few of them hang out on chat. Or you can own up and leave a comment on the post, so when we see the flag and look at the post we know what happened.

Comment: Questions on Meta appear to get the attention of mederators too!

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think about the chat.

Answer (score 3):

Leave a comment below the question clarifying your mistake. Should the respective moderator still happen to dupe-close the question, you should be able to flag the question again, or flag the wrong-dupe stating the issue.

Comment: Yes ;o) This works on EL&U SE too. I had the same problem there last month, false-flagging so to speak, and happened to do what you suggested in the first sentence of this answer (that I just read now). It worked well, and I was told that that was an appropriate thing to do by Meta EL&U users.